# Netlogo: Is there a way to compare strings insensitive to capitalization?

Tags: netlogo

I could not find a way to compare two strings case-insensitive. How could I do this in netlogo?

Comment: There exists a `string` extension for NetLogo (https://github.com/NetLogo/String-Extension), with `upper-case` and `lower-case` reporters, but at the time of writing this comment, that extension hasn't been updated in years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a purpose-built primitive to do this, or even a `to-upper` prim that would make it relatively easy.  You can make a crude utility procedure to do it:

```
to-report equal-ignore-case? [ str1 str2 ]

  if (length str1 != length str2) [ report false ]

  foreach (range length str1) [ i -> 
    let c1 (item i str1)
    let c2 (item i str2)
    ; if c1 = c2, no need to do the `to-upper-char` stuff
    if (c1 != c2 and to-upper-char c1 != to-upper-char c2) [
      report false 
    ]
  ]
  report true
end

; this only works with a string length 1
to-report to-upper-char [ c ]
  let lower "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  let upper "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

  let pos (position c lower)
  report ifelse-value (is-number? pos) [ item pos upper ] [ c ]  
end
```

Then just `equal-ignore-case? "hello" "HELLO"` to compare.

This obviously doesn't work if you care about characters with accents and such.  I make no guarantees for performance, either.